# Java JOptionPane.showInputDialog pop up showing behind all my windows

Tags: java, popup

I'm trying to get a pop up to show on top of all windows and save the value in a variable. But for some reason, the pop up is showing behind all my windows. How can I make sure it pops in front?

Im using import javax.swing.*

`String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"PassWord ")`

Comment: *How can I make sure it pops in front?* - specify proper parameters to the method. Why would you pass in null?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options to show pop up on top:

1. `frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);`
2. `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Hello, World!");` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object)
3. `inputDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(parent);`